# Change For Loop to parallel processing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run a repeated simulation in R in parallel to speed up the processing time (currently the code will take about 2 weeks to run). I have all of the data pre-generated, but the model fitting takes forever. How can I use parallel processing to speed up this process?

Currently I have:

```
results = matrix(NA,num_sims,129)
for (simulation in 1:length(df)){
     LPA1=mplusobject("stuff", rdata = df)
     lpa1_fit = mplusModeler(lpa1, "df.dat", modelout = "lpa1.inp"
     results[simulation,1] = lpa1_fit$results$summaries$BIC
     results[simulation,2] = lpa1_fit$results$summaries$AIC

     LPA2=mplusobject("stuff", rdata = df)
     lpa2_fit = mplusModeler(lpa2, "df.dat", modelout = "lpa2.inp"
     results[simulation,3] = lpa2_fit$results$summaries$BIC
     results[simulation,4] = lpa2_fit$results$summaries$AIC

AND SO ON
}

I get the concept of running this in parallel, but I just can't figure out how to actually execute it.
```

Comment: Here is the documentation for the foreach package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/foreach.pdf
And snow
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/snow.pdf

Comment: Part 1: It is a common misconception, but `foreach()` is _not_ a replacement for the for-loop construct.  Instead, it's an alternative to map-reduce functions such as `lapply()` and `purrr::map()`.  So, to solve your problem, ignore parallelization for now, and figure out how to rewrite your code to use `y <- lapply(...)` or `y <- purrr::map(...)` instead of a for loop.  See <https://www.jottr.org/2019/01/11/parallelize-a-for-loop-by-rewriting-it-as-an-lapply-call/> for a walk-through.

Comment: Part 2: When you have rewritten your code as a `y <- lapply(...)` call, you're in a much better position to write a `y <- foreach(...) %dopar% { ... }` call.  Or, simply use `y <- future_lapply(...)` or `y <- furrr::future_map(...)` to parallelize your code.